Determine Column name/number of the sorting column in Excel
I need a method to return the name (or number) of the column that is being used to sort the sheet.
Is there an Excel formula to do this?

Final edit - I hope.  Ignore the previous solutions, the simplest way to check if a range is sorted is as follows:
 =
  OR(
  AND(A1:A10=SORT(A1:A10)),
  AND(A1:A10=SORT(A1:A10,,-1)))

It checks for both ascending or descending sort order and returns TRUE if the given range is sorted.
The easiest way to do it (but not bullet-proof) would be to use an array formula to test each column returning TRUE/FALSE, something like:
 {=AND(A2:A5<=A3:A6)}


Improved version of the above:

 =AND(A2:A5<=A3:A6) - to calculate if a column is sorted

Only works for ascending sorting but can be easily adjusted for descending as well or even for both if required.
Could also try this approach (add more logic if the data could be sorted by more than one column):


That doesn't need to be an array formula anymore. Nonetheless, it's a good solution!

@michal-rosa   SWEET FANCY MOSES!! That's clever!  Is there a way to use this with mixed column types?  It seems to require the same minimum value on all columns and they need to all be numeric.

@Keng - please see above.

@Enigmativity - good point, thanks, my brain still operates in Excel 2016.
